# Can we return decision based values from a function without using any control structure?

Tags: c++

One of my senior asked me to solve this programming puzzle.

Puzzle:: Make a function that returns 9 if you pass 5 on function call. and return 5 if you pass 9 on function call but you don't use any control structure if,switch ternary operator etc.
I implement this puzzle using bellow mentioned code snippet

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int myFunction(int value){
    return value%5;
}

int main(){
    int myArray[5]={9,5,5,5,5};
    cout<<myArray[myFunction(9)]<<endl
        <<myArray[myFunction(5)];
    return 0;
}
```

suggest more efficient way to solve this puzzle

Comment: Don't spam tags please.

Comment: This should be moved to the code golf site: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to the code golf site: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution might be:

```
unsigned flip59(unsigned x)
{
    return x ^ 12;
}
```

The trick is that bitwise XOR operation can be used to either preserve or negate the bits basing on the mask. Here, the bits at position 2 and 3 are flipped, hence yielding `5 --> 9` and `9 --> 5`.

#### `x = 5:`

```
5 : 0000 0101
12: 0000 1100
^
9 : 0000 1001
```

#### `x = 9:`

```
9 : 0000 1001
12: 0000 1100
^
5 : 0000 0101
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the property of XOR operation:

```
A xor A = 0
0 xor B = B
```

Combined it is giving

```
                 /
                 | A if B == C 
A xor B xor C = <  B if A == C
                 | something else otherwise
                 \
```

So utilizing this you can write a function

```
unsigned int foo(unsigned int x)
{
    return x ^ 5 ^ 9;
}
```

So here it can be either `x == 5` and then it will return `5^5^9=9`, or `x == 9` and then it will return `9^5^9=5`

Answer (score 2):

Cool thing to see how different people do it. This is my solution. It's a no-brainer really. I bet there's a lot more simple solutions!

in short:

```
int function(int i){
  map<int, int> m{{5, 9}, {9, 5}};
  return m[i];
}
```

or long step-wise version + test

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int function(int i)
{
  map<int, int> m;
  m.insert({5, 9});
  m.insert({9, 5});

  return m[i];
}

int main()
{
  cout << function(5) << endl;
  cout << function(9) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the original idea using a smaller lookup table:

```
int get5or9( int x )
{
    const int lookup[] = { 9, 5 };
    return lookup[ ( x >> 3 ) & 1 ];
}
```